# Can I get to Sheol through a challenge run?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

So, I need to beat Sheol with Isaac in *The Binding of Isaac*, can I select the "Doctors Revenge" challenge (which requires you to beat Mom's Heart) and maybe get lucky with a demon room on the Mom's Heart boss to go to Sheol with the Fetus?

Comment: If you get lucky with a Demon Room you can certainly go to Sheol, but what are you hoping to accomplish after beating the challenge?

Comment: unlock moms knife by beating sheol with isaac, i just wanted to know if you can do those simultaneously

Comment: Can't corroborate this personally (seeing how I've beat Sheol with Isaac before challenges existed), but if you ask me fighting Satan with bombs instead of projectiles will **not** be easy, especially in the last phase when he starts trying to stomp you.

Comment: If I recall correctly, completing a challenge immediately returns you to the main menu.

Comment: I believe @badp is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Under most circumstances, no. However, there may be a way to get around that. If you get curse of the labyrinth for your final floors, after you beat the first of the two bosses, it will glitch and give you the achievement and the unlockable. Theoretically at that point you could use the shovel to go to the next floor and continue playing. I can not actually verify that, but it is very likely, although in practice incredibly difficult to do. You are better off trying to beat challenge 1 and then using the candle to easily beat mom (it goes through closed doors) and the devil in sheol (it can hurt the devil while you are fighting the fallen). Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The win condition for "Isaac Was Good Today" is defeating Satan, so for that challenge alone, you can go to Sheol.

EDIT: I was just playing Lord Of The Flies and I defeated Mom's Heart without taking damage, allowing the Devil Room to appear and the game let me go to Sheol. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes you can. Infact **I Did it today***

Firstly, when I played with the Doctor's Revenge, I didn't get hit in my Mom's heart. Then, the *"God" room appeared*

I went in, and was given the item for completing the game. What was interesting was that there ***INDEED*** was a trap door to Sheol.

I did get killed but it is possible.

Though most answers say it is impossible, I got it anyway.
I did it with a few upgrades who made ***Isaac*** look normal, no challenge items, and I used The high priestess against mom's heart

**Hope it helps!**